# How to run shell "time" command every time eclipse runs executable?

Tags: eclipse, shell, time

I want eclipse to print out the time a program takes to execute when it runs. 
I am using Linux Mint, and the shell has a "time" command that I use all the time.

```
 time ./myPgrogram.out
```

I searched if this was possible and I found a post:
[Is there an Eclipse plugin to run system shell in the Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562600/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-to-run-system-shell-in-the-console)

That allows me to use a console in eclipse, but that sucks, first because if I wanted to use the console, I wouldn't be tunning up eclipse in the first time, and second, because Mint's console is a lot better than the one eclipse provides.

So, I wonder, is it possible to make eclipse print out the "time" a program takes to run every time i click the green triangle on the top and run an executable? If so, how?

I also found this thread, but I am not sure if it can help:
[Compiling in Eclipse with gcc's -lpthread and -lrt set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201129/compiling-in-eclipse-with-gccs-lpthread-and-lrt-set)
They use it to link certain commands to eclipse like "-lpthread", I don't know if I can link "time" and print it in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Eclipse but I think you should interested in ["profiler/profiling"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).
It's tool to measuring time and memory used by program and most IDEs have something like this or can use external one.

For example I found [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/GProf/User_Guide) 
(in answer to question [Linux Eclipse CDT profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076602/linux-eclipse-cdt-profiler)).

I don't help you more because I still use "time" in console to test C/C++ programs created in Geany (on Linux Mint) ;).