# Report shows "no time accumulated" for gprof using Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, cygwin, mingw32, gprof

After compiling with flags: `-O0 -p -pg -Wall -c` on GCC and `-p -pg` on the MinGW linker, the eclipse plugin gprof for shows no results. After that I did a cmd call using `gprof my.exe gmon.out > prof.txt`, which resulted in a report witth only the number of calls to functions.

```
Flat profile: 
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
no time accumulated

  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
  0.00      0.00     0.00    16000     0.00     0.00  vector_norm
  0.00      0.00     0.00       16     0.00     0.00  rbf_kernel
  0.00      0.00     0.00        8     0.00     0.00  lubksb
```

I've came across this topic: [gprof reports no time accumulated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030829/gprof-reports-no-time-accumulated). But my program is terminating in a clear maner. Also, [gprof view show no data on MingW/Windows](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197494/), but I am using 32 bits GCC. I have previously tried to use Cygwin, same result.

I am using eclipse Kepler with CDT version 8.3.0.201402142303 and MinGW with GCC 5.4.0.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the question, seems that the code is faster than gprof can measure.

As my application involves a neural network train with several iterations and further testing of kernels, I didn't suspected that a fast code could be causing the problem. I inserted a long loop in the main body and the gprof time was printed.

Comment: close it as self answered then.

Comment: Indeed. Had the same "issue". Apparently, no function call took longer than the sampling time, which is 0.01 seconds. Also, it's not trivial to increase the sampling interval ([reference](http://binutils.sourceware.narkive.com/Qfwc5miT/help-change-the-sampling-time-in-gprof)).