# gprof only showing calls - C program in Ubuntu with WSL1

Tags: c, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gprof

I am having an issue with "gprof" while using WSL1 and "gcc" in Ubuntu. The only information it displays is the "calls" and anything else is set as 0.00. I do not think that is because the program is running too fast because when typing `time ./go` it returns:

```
real = 0.569s; user = 0.547s; sys = 0.000s.
```

The main program (go.c) is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

#define maxloop 1e7

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    int i;
    double x;
    double xsum = 0.0;
    for (i = 1; i < maxloop; i++) {
        x = myFun1(i) + myFun2(i) + myFun3(i);
        xsum += x;
    }
    printf("xsum = %.6f\n", xsum);
    return 0;
}
```

The file with the functions (functions.c) is:

```c
#include <math.h>

double myFun1(double x) {
    double a = sin(x);
    return a;
}

double myFun2(double x){
    double a = pow(x,3);
    return a;
}

double myFun3(double x){
    double a = sqrt(x);
    return a;
}
```

The header (functions.h) is:

```c
double myFun1(double x);
double myFun2(double x);
double myFun3(double x);
```

I am compiling in the terminal as:

```
gcc -pg -o go go.c functions.c -lm
```

Running the gprof as:

```
gprof ./go -p -b
```

[image: What is happening with gprof]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on debian, so maybe it's a WSL1 issue?  Suggest you add a suitable tag.   It's a good idea to include data as text here instead of external images.  You are making it harder than necessarily to help by giving us 2 .c and .h file instead of just a single  .c file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66227779/wsl-gprof-reporting-zero-times has a comment says WSL 2 supports profiling.

Comment: @AllanWind This is my first post here, thanks for the suggestions! I have read this answer, but I would like to keep my codes on Windows and I saw that WSL1 is better for this. In any case I will try to upgrade and test using the WSL2.

Comment: Updating to WSL2 worked just fine and I could still run the programs from Windows folder. Just leaving an update here in case someone appears with the same doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to WSL2 for support of the profiling features required by gprof.